# A working php form

Tags: php, forms, action

I am unable to find a simple working php form anywhere on the net. There is plenty of forms that are in the same file as the rest of the HTML code, but it is just plain confusing when you have 2 or 3 forms in the same  `index.html` file. 
What I'm looking for is just a basic HTML form with `method='post'` and action attribute set to `action='action.php'` , and then making it work in that .php file.

Comment: http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html ?

Comment: You can use jquery submit method for different form

Answer (score 1):

You can put HTML code in PHP file. Here is an example how the code works.

HTML

```
<form action="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="submit" name="test"/>
</form>
```

To check if a form has been submitted or not, use this

PHP

```
if ($_POST['test']) {} // the key "test" should be the same as the name "test" in input type submit.
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider you here three form in single html/php page like

```
<form action="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="submit" name="signin_form"/>
</form>

<form action="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="submit" name="signup_form"/>
</form>

<form action="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="submit" name="password_reset_form"/>
</form>
```

you can see the name attribute on submit button now when user will submit the form the $_POST super global will have the value of submitted button name. and you can check this using this something like

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['signin_form']))
{
    // user submitted the sign in form
}


if(isset($_POST['signup_form']))
{
    // user submitted the sign up form
}


if(isset($_POST['password_reset_form']))
{
    // user submitted the password reset form form
}

?>
```

you can also add a hidden field in each form with the value of form name like

```
<form action="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="sign_in"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="sign_up"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="post" action="action.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="password_reset"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

now you can check in same manner

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['form_type']) && $_POST['form_type'] == 'sign_in')
{
    // user submitted the sign in form
}


if(isset($_POST['form_type']) && $_POST['form_type'] == 'sign_up')
{
    // user submitted the sign up form
}


if(isset($_POST['form_type']) && $_POST['form_type'] == 'password_reset')
{
    // user submitted the password reset form form
}

?>
```